Why my UI is pixelated on build? Unreal engine 4.27 for android
I have an application that only has UI (WidgetsBlueprints) on Unreal Engine 4.27 and when I build and install the apk on severeal devices, the UI is vey pixelated, with low resolution aspect. My app only needs to run on a specific device with Android 11 (similar to android TV) and a 4k UHD screen. I've already tried to change the DPI curve (set all resolutions to scale 1 or 2, scale to fit rule, etc), and also use the r.SetRes 3840x2160f command in console command at the start of the app, but when I do that, the resolution seems to be OK, but only the bottom right corner of the UI is visible. Here's a picture of how the start page of the app is without the console command (with bad resolution UI) and with the console command:

the image with low res UI

the image when I hit that left top button to change to 4k resolution (for test) and run the r.SetRes 3840x2160f console command. The DPI curve is set to default, otherwise I have even more outside parts of my UI in the screen.
Also I've tried a lot of tests with high compress settings, but nothing seems to change the low res aspect. My source textures are with good resolution, when I run on the editor, with mobile preview in Unreal, all looks good, only after the build that happens. Here are other images of what I think could be important, like texture config settings, and other project settings stuff:

The settings configs of all my textures (also tried to change compression to UserInterface2D but that changes nothing about low res aspect, and makes the apk bigger, which I don't want, already have 700mb because the amout of textures)



Some general Android, SDK and NDK project settings config

And User Interface settings with my DPI curve, the 1080 res is the default and projected on UMG, and 2160 is set to scale 2 in curve. Also the aspect of the resolution when the UI is correct on screen looks worse than fullHD (1920x1080) resolution.
Has anyone had a similiar problem or knows how to answer this? What am I missing? Please someone help me with this! 2 weeks struggling with that and no solutions!
